# Highcharts Pie Chart dataLabel Options Don't Work With Object Initialization

Tags: pie-chart

Here is a jsfiddle example where I cannot get data label values or percentages to display when initializing the chart by passing it options when creating the chart object. Only the point.name is displayed in the label. Seems like you can only get these options to work when you create the entire object at run time using the plotOptions structure.

http://jsfiddle.net/nstvx7wc/7/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var options = {

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chartdiv',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },

   pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.name} {point.percentage:.1f} %',
        style: {
               color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
               }
        },
    },
    title: {
           text: ''
           },
};
options.series = [{"colorByPoint": "true", "data": [{"y": 0.36, "name": "series1"}, {"y": 0, "name": "series2"}, {"y": 0, "name": "series3"}, {"y": 0.03, "name": "series4"}, {"y": 0.04, "name": "series5"}, {"y": 0.07, "name": "series6"}]}];
options.title.text = "test pie"; 
options.pie.dataLabels.enabled = 'true';
chartObject = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You 'pie' option was misconfigured. `options.pie` doesn't exist. It should be placed under series or the plotoptions property;

See this example; http://jsfiddle.net/nstvx7wc/21/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = {

    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'test pie'
    }
  };

  options.series = [{
    allowPointSelect: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.name} {point.percentage:.1f} %',
      style: {
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
      }
    },
    "colorByPoint": "true",
    "data": [{
      "y": 0.36,
      "name": "series1"
    }, {
      "y": 0,
      "name": "series2"
    }, {
      "y": 0,
      "name": "series3"
    }, {
      "y": 0.03,
      "name": "series4"
    }, {
      "y": 0.04,
      "name": "series5"
    }, {
      "y": 0.07,
      "name": "series6"
    }]
  }];


  Highcharts.chart('chartdiv', options);
});
```